# DTC not Working after publish to IIS

Tags: sql-server, wcf, iis, msdtc

I have a project that use DTC and works well locally both in IIS and VS. but when I publish it on my servers it's not working.

Software runs queries on multi databases. I have a web server that gets the HTTP requests and then passes it to Business Layer (a separated server via WCF) and then Business Layer uses EF to run query on SQL Server (separated machine), but it cant use DTC,

DTC is enabled on all servers.

Is it a requirement for DTC to have a SQL Server DBMS on Business server?

I get Internal Error on Client. What should I do?

All of my machines are virtual (using esXi 5.5) and OS:

- SQL Server: Win2008R2 - SQLServer2008R2
- Business: Win2008R2 - WCF Service
- Web server: Win2008R2 - ASP.Net

[Edited]

### More Description:

Error in Event viewer:
msdtc encountered an error (HR+0x80000171) while attempting to secure connection with system STORAGE

configured based on:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753620(WS.10).aspx
allowedinbound and outbound

Comment: *DTC is enabled on all servers* - this statement is meaningless. DTC may be enabled but how is it configured? *Is it a requirement for DTC to have a SQL Server* - No, DTC does not require SQL server. Neither does SQL server require DTC. *I get Internal Error on Client* - even though we are powerful, we have not yet evolved the capability to see your computer display. You are going to have to tell us the what the error says.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure what you mean by *can DTC works with IP?*. DTC is a service designed for the propagation of transactions across multiple machines. Those machines must be on the same domain on a network. It is a heavyweight solution which introduces much complexity and performance penalties. It is best avoided.

Comment: @tomredfern I mean can we have 2 machines in separated domains with valid IP?

Comment: Not sure about this. IIRC DTC does not work cross domain. But you'll need to check. I may be wrong